# Why throwing error logs an error: Uncaught ....(error message)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have this code:

```
export const checkIfUsernameExists = username => 
    db.child(username).once("value", snap => 
        {if(snap.exists()) throw "Username already in use"})
```

If I call it (in another file):

```
checkIfUsernameExists(username)
    .catch(err => this.setState({err})
```

It's working because it throws an error, but not the right way. It logs: `Uncaught Username already in use` to the console, but I want to set this message to the React state.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation for `checkIfUsernameExists` uses the callback signature variant for `firebase.database.Query#once`.

You want to use the Promise variant to apply Promise style error handling.

```
db.child(username)
  .once("value")
  .then(snap => {
     if(snap.exists()) {
        throw Error("Username already in use");
     }
  })
```

Another way if you like to keep the current callback style is to refactor `checkIfUsernameExists` to accept a callback.

```
export const checkIfUsernameExists = username, cb => 
    db.child(username).once("value", cb)
```

Say you have `onUsernameExists` method defined in your component.

```
const USERNAME_IN_USE = "Username already in use";
//...
onUsernameExists = snap => {
   if(snap.exists()) {
     this.setState(() => ({errText: USERNAME_IN_USE})) 
   }
}
```

Then `checkIfUsernameExists` can be called this way.

```
checkIfUsernameExists(username, this.onUsernameExists);
```